# Socketio Rapid Refresh doesn't fire disconnect

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, chatroom

I am working on a room-based application using Flask.  Each room and its members are tracked in a Postgresql database via SQL-Alchemy.  The Users are anonymous, and thus temporary: they are only persisted in the database for as long as they are in a room.

Everything works as intended under 'normal' usage conditions: joining a room via a url or refreshing the page once or twice.  However, if the user is refreshing the page many times in quick succession (e.g. spamming the browser's refresh button), issues start to occur. The connection event gets fired properly, but the disconnect event is never run.  As a result, the user is still considered to be in the room according to the database.  This inaccurate data causes a bunch of other issues.  Why does the disconnect event not fire, and is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks,
Michael

Code run on connect:

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def add_to_room_and_sync_client():

    print('------------------------ user has connected!!!')
    print(request.sid)

    room = session['room_hash']

    # Add user to room
    join_room(room)
    RoomManager.join_room(room)

    # Broadcast connection to all users in room
    username = session['username']
    emit('statusUpdate', {'username':session['username'], 'status':'joining'}, room=room)

    # Get newly connected client up-to-date
    emit('sync', cache_manager.get_data_structures(session['room_hash']))
```

Code for leaving:

```
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect_user():
    print('user has disconnected!-------------------------')

    url = request.headers['Referer'] 
    room = url.split('/')[-1]

    leave_room(room)
    RoomManager.leave_room(room)

    username = session['username']
    emit('statusUpdate', {'username':session['username'], 'status':'leaving'}, room=room)
```

Relevant code from RoomManager:

```
class RoomManager():
def join_room(hash_):
        room = Room.query.filter_by(id=hash_).first()

        # Add user to database if they do not exist.  Otherwise, select them from database
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=session['user_id']).first()
        if user == None:
            user = User(session['user_id'], session['username'])

        # Add user to room list. Also, if there is currently no owner, 
        # give this user ownership of the room
        room.users.append(user)

        if room.owner == None:
            room.owner = user

        db.session.commit()
def leave_room(hash_):
        room = Room.query.filter_by(id=hash_).first()
        user = User.query.filter_by(id=session['user_id']).first()


        # Remove user from room
        room.users.remove(user)

        # If this user was the owner, make someone else the owner
        if room.owner == user:
            print('he owns it')
            if len(room.users) == 0:
                room.owner = None
            else:
                room.owner = room.users[0]

        # If this is the only room the user is in, remove them from the database
        if len(user.rooms) == 0:
            db.session.delete(user)

        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Socket disconnect happens in 2 cases: a client explicitly sent a disconnect packet via socket (which may not happen if page is closed) or client haven't [responded to pings in a certain interval of time](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/blob/master/socketio/asyncio_server.py#L39) which is 60 sec by default. Try waiting for that time.

Comment: @Fian I am aware of the ping_timeout feature, the event still isn't being triggered.

socketio = SocketIO(ping_interval=2, ping_timeout=4)

This is my current configuration, which means the disconnect event should be fired 4 seconds after the client disconnects.  However, the disconnect even is not fired after 4 seconds.  In fact, as far as I can tell, it is never fired (I have tried waiting 10 minutes for it).